# I need MySQL for website, but can't install it on www.pythonanywhere.com's server

Tags: mysql-python, pythonanywhere

I tried `pip install MySQL-python --user`
I get these errors:

[image: First error]

[image: Second error]

[image: Third error]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: There are images. click on  them:                                                                                First error

Second error

Third error.

Comment: But the link says "Why NOT ...."  

Comment: Can you add info about the version of MySQL, and the version if Python you are using (please also add the OS, and version).

Comment: @ I want to install MySQL on pythonanywhere linux server, version of MySQL is 1.2.5 and python is 3.9

Comment: 2 out of 5 systems (see: [this](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/), servers 'classic' and 'dangermouse' ) seems to already have MySQL-python installed

Comment: Maybe this helppage does help: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL

Comment: I try this command pip install mysqlclient   --user  and now MySQL works